# Do I need to scale categorical variables which have numeric values for K-means clustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

4    203
8    103
6     84
3      4
5      3
Name: cyl, dtype: int64

This is column named 'cyl' for cylinder, showing the number of cylinders ranging from 3-8 cylinders in a car engine. So do I need to scale these type of features ?

I am confused as to whether scaling or not scaling will affect the performance of the K-means clustering algorithm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No you do not scale categorical values. You make dummy variables from cat. https://www.southampton.ac.uk/passs/confidence_in_the_police/multivariate_analysis/linear_regression.page

Comment: you mean One Hot encoding ? , can I not leave it as it is and apply K-means @GedasMiksenas

Comment: Read this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data and  this https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-algorithm-for-data-with-mixed-categorical-and-numerical-features-d4e3a48066a0